# java drivers for data acquisition hardware?

Tags: java, device-driver, data-acquisition

I need to do some data acquisition & would like to use Java to program my data acquisition application. Right now I am using a LabJack which has a Java wrapper for its driver & it's working ok for simple stuff but I need to upgrade to something real.

anyone aware of a data acquisition platform (NI or Measurement Computing or one of the others) that has Java device drivers available?

Answer (score 2):

I've used the [Phidget](http://www.phidgets.com/) hardware before, but it's really hobby level. Worked a treat though.

Comment: Interesting, i'll have to check it out. It sounds like it's on the level of Labjack. But I bet the Java driver end of things is more difficult than the analog signal conditioning. (At least it would be for me :D )

Comment: oh, the analog sampling rates are pretty slow :(
(65 samples a second for the 1018)

Answer (score 1):

I am currently developing for National Instruments hardware under Java, with the obvious drawback that NI doesn't support Java.

Also I'm taking advantage of an existing framework called JAW
http://www.aplu.ch/jaw/

With some reading, controlling the cards is a breeze. Note: It only works under Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out this [wikibook](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Serial_Programming:Serial_Java). I knew about Javaconn, but didn't know it had been withdrawn. I believe most of this hardware comes with serial interfaces.

Comment: thanks, but data acquisition (except for simple polling) has higher data rates and more complicated timing than plain serial I/O. Much of data acquisition is about scheduling regularly-sampled ADCs and gathering it into memory on the PC via DMA.